# R: Sort matrix based on amount of row values

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix with non numeric-values (missing values are blank, not Nan).

```
mat = read.table(textConnection(
"   s1  s2  s3
g1  a;b  a  b
g2       b   
g3  a       a;b"), row.names = 1, header = TRUE, sep = "\t", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
mat = as.matrix(mat)
```

What I want to do is to subset the matrix to select the rows with the two highest values in a row.

So the result should be

```
g1  a;b  a  b # with three values
g3  a       a;b # with two values
# g2 should be excluded because it only has one value
```

My approach would be

- sort matrix by amount of values
- subset sorted matrix

But I do not understand how to sort a matrix by the amount of entries.

Any ideas?

Comment: So you want to count the cells in a matrix that have values, sort by this count, and drop the rows under some threshold?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something with the `apply` by the row and check how many elements in the row is an empty string, then sort by the count. So the sorted matrix would be like:

```
mat[order(apply(mat, 1, function(row) sum(row != "")), decreasing = T), ]
   s1    s2  s3   
g1 "a;b" "a" "b"  
g3 "a"   ""  "a;b"
g2 ""    ""  "b"
```

Say if the threshold is 2, you can also specify it in the function directly without sorting:

```
mat[apply(mat, 1, function(row) sum(row != "") >= 2), ]
   s1    s2  s3   
g1 "a;b" "a" "b"  
g3 "a"   ""  "a;b"
```

Another way as suggested by @alexis_laz is using `rowSums`:

```
mat[rowSums(mat != "") >= 2, ]
   s1    s2  s3   
g1 "a;b" "a" "b"  
g3 "a"   ""  "a;b"
```

Comment: `apply` call can be avoided since `!=` works in a "vectorised" way; `rowSums(mat != "")`. Also, `nchar` and `nzchar` could be handy, too, comparing against `""`.

Comment: @alexis_laz Always forget about that. I am keeping doing this all the time. Thanks for pointing that out.